# Preg_ match using?

Tags: preg-match

I use preg_match to the program like this

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+\:/{1,2}', $filename))
```

But it shows an error like this

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '{'
```

how to change this?

Comment: What do you want to match?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing '/' at the end of the regex and you should escape '/' in the regex itself. This should work i.e. warning should be gone (ignoring if regex you've written is doing what you want):

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+\:\/{1,2}/', $filename))
```